# Laravel : How to take last n(any number) rows after ordered in ascending order?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, laravel, laravel-4

1. I have 3 columns `id`, `msg` and `created_at` in my Model table. `created_at` is a timestamp and `id` is primary key.
2. I also have 5 datas, `world => time4`, `hello => time2`,`haha => time1`,`hihio => time5` and `dunno => time3` and these datas are arranged in ascending order (as arranged here) based on their `id`.

In laravel 4, I want to fetch these data, arrange them in ascending order and take the last n(in this case, 3) number of records. So, I want to get `dunno`,`world` and `hihio` rows displayed like this in a div :

```
dunno,time3
world,time4
hihio,time5
```

**What I have tried**

```
Model::orderBy('created_at','asc')->take(3);
```

undesired result :

```
haha,time1
hello,time2
dunno,time3
```

**Also tried**

```
Model::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3);
```

undesired result :

```
hihio,time5
world,time4
dunno,time3
```

**I have also tried the reverse with no luck**

```
Model::take(3)->orderBy('created_at','asc');
```

This problem seems fairly simple but I just can't seem to get my logic right. I'm still fairly new in Laravel 4 so I would give bonus points to better solutions than using `orderBy()` and `take()` if there is. Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(3)`, and then reverse the array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are very close.

It sounds like you want to first order the array by descending order

```
  Model::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3);
```

but then reverse the array. You can do this one of two ways, either the traditional PHP (using array_reverse).

```
  $_dates = Model::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3);
  $dates = array_reverse($_dates);
```

Or the laravel way, using the `reverse` function in Laravel's `Collection` class.

```
  $_dates = Model::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3)->reverse();
```

Check out Laravel's `Collection` documentation at their API site at http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html

Now $dates will contain the output you desire.

```
dunno,time3
world,time4
hihio,time5
```

Answer (score 4):

You're pretty close with your second attempt. After retrieving the rows from the database, you just need to reverse the array. Assuming you have an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`, you just need to the following:

```
$expectedResult = $collection->reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get last three rows in ascending order:

```
$_dates = Model::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3)->reverse();
```

Now, the json output of $_dates will give you a object of objects.

To get array of objects use:

```
$_dates = Model::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3)->reverse()->values();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$reverse = Model::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3);

$show = $reverse->reverse();
```