# How to find all users who comment all the articles commented by a given user?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I have following problem in my HW.

> List the userID, username and last login date of user/s who comment
>   all the articles commented by a given user. (given userID)

This is my table format:

```
user(userID:char(10), username:char(30), registrationDate:date,lastLoginDate:date),
article(articleID:char(10), userID:char(10), name:char(80), description:char(130), date:date, rating:int),
comment(commentID:char(10), articleID:char(10), userID:char(10), message:char(130), date:date, rating:int),
```

I have tried the following query to find people who comment all the articles commented by a given user. For example, the given user id is U102;

```
select C.articleID,U.userID, U.username, U.LastLoginDate from user U, comment C where U.userID = C.userID AND C.articleID IN (select articleID from comment where userID= 'U102');
```

Then following is my output here:

```
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------------+
| articleID | userID | username       | LastLoginDate |
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------------+
| A105      | U101   | Jon Skeet      | 2016-11-29    |
| A105      | U102   | Darin Dimitrov | 2016-11-28    |
| A104      | U105   | VonC           | 2016-11-25    |
| A104      | U101   | Jon Skeet      | 2016-11-29    |
| A104      | U102   | Darin Dimitrov | 2016-11-28    |
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------------+
```

However, this is not what I want. What I expect is :

```
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------------+
| articleID | userID | username       | LastLoginDate |
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------------+
| A105      | U101   | Jon Skeet      | 2016-11-29    |
| A105      | U102   | Darin Dimitrov | 2016-11-28    |
| A104      | U101   | Jon Skeet      | 2016-11-29    |
| A104      | U102   | Darin Dimitrov | 2016-11-28    |
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: I tried a lot, but i am unable to do it. I am new to SQL, so i am trying to learn. Whether it is my own open source project or HW, the main purpose here is to understand writing SQL queries.

Comment: Understanding SQL queries can be done by reading tutorial and googling. There are tons of them out there. Again, first, tell us  **what you've tried in detail** then tell us what problem you have encountered. Or rather, google the problem first before asking on SO. SO community will only help if they can see that **you put in effort**. Just saying you've tried a lot still begs the same question I've asked earlier, **what have you tried?**

Comment: I understand you, and edited my question said what i have tried.

Comment: Break it into smaller, simpler pieces and then build up from there. Eg: First find all the articles commented on by the user, then find all the other commenters on those articles, etc. [hint: you'll probably need a JOIN or two]

Comment: @ABUBAKAR That's a good first step! Now, tell us what **problem you've encountered** or why you're not satisfied with the sql result. E.g., *I want to get _____ but it's showing ______. How do I get _____ ?* Finally, **edit your question** to *How do I get_____?* instead of just saying, "SQL Command Query". After you've done that, your question will be alright. As your question gets better, others will likely be more helpful.

Comment: @ABUBAKAR you may look at my question for guidance on how to write a question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154208/laravel-how-to-take-last-nany-number-rows-after-ordered-in-ascending-order

Comment: @Sammitch I tried from going small piece, i will check for using join also.

Comment: Btw, your output seems correct... or are you wanting just the other users excluding user `U102`?

Comment: Darin Dimitrov (the given user)  commented on A104 and A105. John Skeet did the same. But, VonC did commented only on the A104. I want to exclude VonC here since he did not commented on every article that Darin Dimitrov is commented also (A105 is missing).